# Replace "null" to "0" in json only for int or use Nullable<int>?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'll try to describe my situation:

I have Windows Store App (C#), which receive data from remote data base (`DataBase1`), and store it in local database in isolated storage (`DataBase2`). I have single class for all manipulation with data for ex:

```
[Table("Table")]
[DataContract]
public class Class1
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [Column("id")]
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; } 
}
```

This class can take 50+ fields.
I use [Newtonsoft.Json](http://json.codeplex.com/):

```
 var class = JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<Class1>(json);
```

All works great, but in `DataBase1` all fields have `default value = null`, and when I receive null I have exception.

I have 2 ideas how to solve it:

1. make `int Id` -> `int? Id`, and in setter change "null" to "0" (and always work with nulleable type), but I'm not sure about performance.
2. make another nullable field (`int? IdCanBeNull`), where store value from DataBase1, then in `IdCanBeNull`s setter set nested value to `Id` and always work with `int Id` (not nullable type) (save it in `DataBase2` and other). Better performance, but need to create 2xNumberOfFields

My questions is:
 Which is right way?
 May be you have another idea, how to store "null" to "0" with using `Newtonsoft.Json`.
 Try to explain your answer.

Note:

1. Yes, when I receive json I can remove all "null" to "0" - but it's isn't good solution.
2. I can't change default value of `DataBase1`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a third way. You can write a converter class for this

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(
                            "[{Id:5},{Id:0},{Id:null},{}]",
                             new MyConverter());


public class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(int);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value == null) return 0;
        return Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using JsonConverter settings to ignore null characters:

```
    Person person = new Person
{
    Name = "Nigal Newborn",
    Age = 1
};

string jsonIncludeNullValues = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented);

Console.WriteLine(jsonIncludeNullValues);
// {
//   "Name": "Nigal Newborn",
//   "Age": 1,
//   "Partner": null,
//   "Salary": null
// }

string jsonIgnoreNullValues = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
});

Console.WriteLine(jsonIgnoreNullValues);
// {
//   "Name": "Nigal Newborn",
//   "Age": 1
// }
```

more info on:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm